# Keep zoom when refreshing webpage

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, gps

Good evening everyone. Right now I'm developing a gps localisation web server, I'm getting the coordinates from a GPS card to a port sniffer in the server, it writes the coordinates in a SQL database. 
The issue I'm experiencing is that I'm constantly refreshing the webpage to fetch new data but if the user zooms in or zooms out, or moves the center at the time of refreshing all this changes get lost.

this is the JS fragment:

```
    <script>
// functions below
//Make an array with the coordinates from the db
function initialize() {
    var posicion= [];
    for (var i=0; i< lat.length; i++){
    posicion.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i], long[i])); // Add the coordinates
    }

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
     center: posicion[lat.length-1],
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); // Render our map within the empty div

  var linea = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: posicion,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  linea.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);  
</script>
```

Comment: I'd probably use a [hash in the url](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp). Set it when the user zooms, and read it when the page loads (if it's there)

Comment: I think you should try to use something like ajax, rather than refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen the event "bounds_changed" and then save the results on cookies. When you reeload you use those values as default for zoom and center

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', (function () {
  var centerTobeSavedOnCookie = map.getCenter();
  var zoomTobeSavedOnCookie = map.getZoom();
  // save values to cookies
  setCookie("gmapDefaultZoom", zoomTobeSavedOnCookie, 1);
  setCookie("gmapDefaultCenter", centerTobeSavedOnCookie , 1);
}()));

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution but I'm sure I'm using wrongly the cookies :(